# Do "Ors" Evaluate The Whole Expression?

Tags: performance, optimization, logic

Say I have the following statement logic (I'll be using VBA for this example, but it also pertains to other languages)

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 1000
If x = 1 Or y = 2 Or z = 4 Then
     Execute Code
End
```

Does the compiler or executing program find that the first value is true, and then continue to `Execute Code` or does it finish off the rest of the statement?

Comment: In some languages (e.g. C *et al*) the logical operators are short-circuit, in others not - you'll need to be more specific about which language(s) you are interested in.

Comment: Since there are no side-effects in that expression, you can't tell the difference anyway.

Comment: @harold, you could if say, SQL was looping through hundreds of thousand of records and evaluating a situation similar to the situation exampled above. This question is based on curiosity more than trying to solve a current problem.

Comment: Fair enough, you *could* have side-effects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for VBA, but I can say that it is language specific. In some languages, the programmer has the ability to use "short-circuit" AND and OR expressions. Short-circuiting is the process of no longer evaluating a boolean expression if the result has already been determined.

If using a short-circuited AND, the boolean operation stops early if a FALSE is found. If using a short-circuited OR, the boolean operation stops early if a TRUE is found.

For example, in Java:

`a || b` is a short-circuited OR

`a | b` is a non-short-circuited OR

`a && b` is a short-circuited AND

`a & b` is a non-short-circuited AND

Some may ask, "why would I ever use a non-short-circuited AND or OR?" The reason for this comes when you are calling a function that returns a boolean that you want to run in every case. For example `a() | b()` would run both function a and function b. `a() || b()` only runs function b if a returns false.

Comment: I chose yours as the answer due to the mentioning of the "Short-Circuit" logic, and explanation of when it should be used. Thanks.

Comment: If it's vital to do execute both `a()` and `b()` then one would be better off with calling both in separate statements and then OR-ing them, to be clearer they were both needed. As was pointed out to me recently, `a() | b()` can be faster than `a() || b()` in cases where the cost of calculating a redundant `b()` is outweighed by the cost of branching introduced by the short-circuit.

Answer (score 1):

I think that also in vba you can use OrElse.

'Or' (bitwise comparison) always finishes the rest of the statement, 'OrElse' (logical comparison) stops when the requirement is met.
In C++, C# and Java you can use '|' and '||'.

For example `if object is null Or object.value = ""` will result in a null exception when the object is empty because of the attempt to access a field from an empty object.

With OrElse the evaluation `if object is null OrElse object.value = ""` will stop at the first comparison when an empty object is evaluated.

Comment: OrElse (And the related AndAlso) are both VB.NET functions.

Comment: They are, they were added to VB.NET to give it an ability to short-circuit that VB did not have (baring explicit `IF ... THEN` branching) but many other languages do have. This makes comparison between C# and VB.NET in particular, easier.